# Set password for .mdf file in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, mdf

**Set pssword for .mdf file in sqlserver**.

When you attach a file to someone, I want to ask him the password. In both cases, windows authorization and sqlserver authorization.

Comment: @ Mojtaba Shamsabadi You can not set password for .mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt a database using tde which will prevent anyone from attaching an mdf file to another instance. It uses certificates and as usual simple talk has a great article as to how to use it and how it works. If someone has the correct certificate they can attach it.